# How do IoT Edge "internal" messages count against my message quota?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

IoT Hub is billed based on number of messages per day (including updating and retrieval of twins, etc).  We know that IoT Edge uses some internal messages to operate, such as the reported health/status updates that appear in the portal for it's modules, retrieval of it's own device twin. module twins, etc.

How does this traffic affect the messages against my daily quota?  i.e what "counts"?  My expectation would be that explicit twin updates/retrievals from custom modules would count, but does the edgeAgent/edgeHub traffic count?  If it does, how often does that happen?

Doesn't seem to be a lot of traffic, but it affects pricing and sizing IoT solutions, so needs to be factored in.

--Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IoT Edge is "free" with IoT Hub (i.e. the features are available on all IoT hubs; you don't have to bring in/pay for a separate resource), but you do pay for all traffic. Mostly that will just be your traffic (messages your devices/modules are sending/receiving), but Edge Agent and Edge Hub do twin operations when the edge device is starting up, and when things change. So if you deploy a new module to your edge device you'll see some Edge Agent twin traffic related to that. If you change some routes, you'll see the corresponding Edge Hub twin traffic.

As the product nears general availability, you can expect to see documentation that outlines how the Agent and Hub are using their twins, so you know what to expect.